# How do I prevent my 'unused' global variables being compiled out of my static library?

Tags: c++, global-variables

I'm using static initialisation to ease the process of registering some classes with a factory in C++. Unfortunately, I think the compiler is optimising out the 'unused' objects which are meant to do the useful work in their constructors. Is there any way to tell the compiler not to optimise out a global variable?

```
class SomeClass {
    public:
        SomeClass() {
            /* do something useful */
        }
};

SomeClass instance;
```

My breakpoint in SomeClass's constructor doesn't get hit. In my actual code, SomeClass is in a header file and instance is in a source file, more or less alone.

EDIT: As guessed by KJAWolf, this code is actually compiled into a static lib, not the executable. Its purpose is to register some types also provided by the static lib with a static list of types and their creators, for a factory to then read from on construction. Since these types are provided with the lib, adding this code to the executable is undesirable.

Also I discovered that by moving the code to another source file that contains other existing code, it works fine. It seems that having a file purely consisting of these global objects is what's causing the problem. It's as if that translation unit was entirely ignored.

Comment: Is your source file part of the executable, or is it part of a static library?

Comment: Aha, good divining work. Actually the source file is part of a static lib. Would that cause a problem? I'm 80% sure I've done the exact same thing before and it's worked.

Comment: i had the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599035/force-visual-studio-to-link-all-symbols-in-a-lib-file

Comment: Why are you using a global variable?

Comment: As I said, to execute some code at static initialisation time, to register a class with a factory. I made the conscious decision to use them for this purpose, in case this is leading into a lecture :) The reason I'm having trouble is that I'm a good programmer, so I never really use them and don't understand why they're not working as I expect!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The compiler is not allowed to optimiza away global objects.
Even if they are never used.

Somthing else is happening in your code.
Now if you built a static library with your global object and that global object is not referenced from the executable it will not be pulled into the executable by the linker.

Comment: I've upvoted this because I think it's the only answer that nails the real problem; As the questioner says "It seems that having a file purely consisting of these global objects is what's causing the problem. It's as if that translation unit was entirely ignored". The translation unit is being ignored in the sense that it is being omitted by the linker because it's in a library. If an object is in a library and isn't called by anything in the app, it's omitted, that's the whole idea of libaries!

Comment: Ditto, that hit the nail on the head. I upvoted Pavel's answer too since he also got it right :)

Comment: @Sam: How to fix it depends on what you are doing. Using global objects just for the side-effects of their construction/destruction is not really a good idea.

Comment: There seems to be a good solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599035/force-visual-studio-to-link-all-symbols-in-a-lib-file

Comment: I have the same experience and it's awful (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e4d1a04-fa66-47a6-bc55-7bd9f2b9494b/constructors-for-global-variables-are-not-called?forum=vclanguage). The globals weren't referenced but their constructors had observable side effects (i.e. registering at a factory). I ended up making artificial references to these global objects to prevent removal. Only if the linker can prove that globals don't do anything THEN it may throw them away afaiac.

Comment: It seems the C++ standard -does- allow to optimizing away global objects in a translation unit if no function in that translation unit is ever referenced. While the second part of the answer implicitly says that, the first part of the answer appears incorrect as written. See https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.vc.language/c/RakxA8jHEvU/m/qO8eU6Tt4ugJ

Comment: @Danra That's not a reliable source. Do you have a reference to the standard? This answer as written is correct to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: This seems to say something of the sort for modules https://eel.is/c++draft/module.reach#footnote-93

Answer (score 5):

The compiler should never optimize away such globals - if it does that, it is simply broken.

Comment: If the compiler can detect no use of the global, it can omit them.  GCC (G++ in this context) can and does omit some variables - for example, the old 'embed a version in the object file' tricks do not work with modern GCC - the file static value is detected as unused and optimized out of the object file.

Comment: If they have a cnstructor then there is a potential side affect from using the constructor. As gcc does not do cross function analysis it would never be able to detect the potential of a side affect and thus would not be allowed to remove it.

Comment: What Martin said. If constructor has an observable side effect, it cannot be removed regardless of whether it's static or not. Also, I'm not sure I understand your remark, Neil - IIRC, the C spec doesn't define "global" in any way, so its definition is open, and "global is anything that's not local or member" is a fairly reasonable one (though not the only one, obviously).

Comment: @Pavel Something like static int x; obviously cannot be "global" and could definitely be elided by the compiler. My point was that things that might be global (i.e. linked to by other compilation units) cannot be elided by the compiler, constructor or no, because the compiler cannot know if they are going to be linked to.

Comment: It's still a global as far as I'm concerned (it's visible by all functions in the compilation unit, so what is it then?), but arguing term definitions is pointless. However, even for a "static global", if its constructor has _observable side effects_, the compiler cannot legally elide it.

Comment: Well, of course it isn't so visible (depending on where it is defined), but we seem to be at cross purposes. I've nowhere said that that I disagree with the point about constructor elidation

Answer (score 2):

You can force that one object (your list of types) pulls some other objects with it by **partially linking** them before building the complete static lib.

With [GNU linker](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/):

```
ld -Ur -o TypeBundle.o type1.o type2.o type3.o static_list.o
ld -static -o MyStaticLib.a type_bundle.o other_object.o another_object.o ...
```

Thus, whenever the static list is referenced by code using the library, the complete "TypeBundle.o" object will get linked into the resulting binary, including type1.o, type2.o, and type3.o.

While at it, do check out the meaning of "-Ur" in [the manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options).

Answer (score 1):

To build off of Arthur Ulfeldt, volatile tells the compiler that this variable can change outside of the knowledge of the compiler.  I've used it for put a statement to allow the debugger to set a breakpoint.  It's also useful for hardware registers that can change based on the environment or that need a special sequence.  i.e. Serial Port receive register and certain watchdog registers.

Comment: No, it simply tells the compiler that it must not cache a previously read value of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
#pragma optimize off
int globalVar
#pragma optimize on
```

but I dunno if that only works in Visual Studio ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k(VS.80).aspx ).

You could also tell the compiler to not optimize at all, especially if you're debugging...

Comment: This is not compatible with every IDE/compilers.

Comment: but I wish it were!

Comment: On Visual Studio the syntax is #pragma optimize("", off) but for me it doesn't prevent the global variable to be removed in a static library.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using gcc with gdb?  There was a problem in the past where gdb could not accurately set breakpoints in constructors.

Also, are you using an optimization level which allows the compiler to inline methods in the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

I have same setup & problem on VS2008.
I found that if you declare you class with `dllexport` it will not optimize.

```
class __declspec( dllexport ) Cxxx
{
.
}
```

However this generates a lot of warnings in my case because I must declare all classes used in this class also as dllexport.

All optimizations are off (in debug mode), still this is optimized. Also volatile/pragma optimize off. On global variable created of this class (in same cpp file) etc does not work.

Just found that dllexport does require at least to include header files of these classes in some other cpp file from exe to work! So only option is to add a file with calls to some static members for each class, and add this file to all projects used these classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -whole-archive when linking. See the answer here:

[ld linker question: the --whole-archive option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805555/ld-linker-question-the-whole-archive-option)

Answer (score 0):

It would not be a compiler, but the library linker (or the tool that pools object files into the .lib), who can decide that the whole file is not used, so discard it.
A workaround would be to add an empty function to that file and call it from a file that contains stuff that is called directly.

Answer (score -1):

How about using the keyword volatile? It will prevent the compiler from too much optimization.

Comment: Sometimes, this is somehow useful.