# How to get a statement run in global scope in C++

Tags: c++, scope, global-variables

For solving some exercise I need to have global objects run in a C++ code like below. But when I run it using MS VS compiler, that global variable will not be run.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    class Tracer {
        string cons, dest;
    public:
        Tracer(string c, string d) : cons(c), dest(d) {
            cout << "A(n) '" << cons << "' object was created.\n";
        }

        void mem_ob() {
            Tracer<string> s("string", "string");
        }

        ~Tracer() {
            cout << "The '" << dest << "' object was destructed.\n";
        }
    };

    //----------------------------

    Tracer<double> d("double", "double");

   //------------------------------------

    int main() {
        Tracer<int> t("int", "int");
        t.mem_ob();

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

The `d` object isn't run. How to get it run please?

Comment: What version are you using (service pack) ? This works on gcc/VS2013, can't test on 2015 atm.

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't run ? Using `g++`  5.3 every texts are displayed (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4b98db81858a5d2)

Comment: the `d`object is not linked if you have have activated some optimization. These optimizations are activated if you compile in Release mode.

Comment: Did you try in debug mode ?

Comment: I'd run it in Debug mode.

Comment: @norisknofun: Are you sure? It is allowed to lazily initialize globals from other Translation Units, but every global in the TU of `main` must be initialized before `main` is called.

Comment: well the compilation step evaluates _all_ source code. But at the link step, the linker starts from the `main` method and gathers the _needed_ code. So, we can see the `d` global variable is not used any where. So there is no reason to include this code. In DEBUG mode, all is linked but his mainly depends of the linkage options.

Comment: Similar issues/workarounds discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229430/how-do-i-prevent-my-unused-global-variables-being-compiled-out), though in that case the problem seemed to be that `d` was in a library, rather than the main executable - is that a detail you're neglecting to mention, franky. thinking it unimportant?