# Clang C++ Template Singleton in plugins

Tags: c++, linker, singleton

I'm trying to understand how C++/Clang deals with static members in templates. To that end I defined a `Singleton` as follows:

```
template <class T> class Singleton {
public:
    static T* instance() {
        if (!m_instance)
            m_instance = new T;

        return m_instance;
    }

private:
    static T* m_instance;
};

template <class T> T* Singleton<T>::m_instance = nullptr;
```

This appears to work just fine provided my application is compiled as a single executable. When I start using plugins, i.e. `dylib`s opened with `dlopen`, I get multiple instances of the `Singleton`.

Normally I compile my application with `-fvisiblity=hidden`. If remove that option, meaning I use `default` visibility, then the `Singleton`s behave properly. This led me to think I just need to export the symbol using `__attribute__((visibility=default))` but this doesn't work.

What is going here, and what would the solution be?

Comment: That might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398069/static-member-variable-in-template-with-multiple-dlls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the suggestions in [PiotrNycz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1463922/piotrnycz)'s linked answer, the simplest solution for me was to add a visible explicit instantiation of template in a cpp file in the module where the type inheriting from `Singleton` was defined. A one-liner was sufficient:

```
template<> __attribute__((visibility=default)) MyType * Singleton<MyType>::m_instance = nullptr;
```

This will make the `MyType` instance of the `Singleton` template visible as an exported symbol in just one module. To avoid duplicate symbols the initialization of `m_instance` has to be removed from the definition of `Singleton`, i.e. delete this line:

```
template <class T> T* Singleton<T>::m_instance = nullptr;
```